# Meteor: Uncaught ReferenceError: calcRoute is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, meteor, meteor-helper

I am new to Meteor and Javascript. I am creating a map that gives directions from your current location to a marker on the map. Everything seems to work except that I can't seem to call the calcRoute() function correctly. Or maybe it is defined in the wrong place.

I think I need some schooling on template helpers. Please tell me where I went wrong. Thanks.

```
    var gmaps = {

    // map object
    map: null,

    //direction services object
    directionsService: null,

    //direction services object
    directionsDisplay: null,

    //direction services object
    stepDisplay: null,

    markerArray: []
} 
Template.map.helpers({
    mapOptions: function() {
        if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {

            if (!Geolocation.error()) {                
                pos = Geolocation.latLng();
            } 
            return {
                //center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.2743, 133.7751),
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.lat, pos.lng),
                zoom: 12,
                scaleControl: false,                
                zoomControl: false,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                panControl: false,
                rotateControl: true,
                overviewMapControl: false, 
                streetViewControl: false,


            };
        }
    },

     calcRoute: function() {


        //clear markers before calculating function   
        gmaps.clearMarkers();    

        console.log(this.markerArray);
        // Retrieve the start and end locations and create
        // a DirectionsRequest using BICYCLING directions.
        var start = marker3.getPosition(); 
        var end = document.getElementById('marketName').value;
        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.BICYCLING
        };

        // Route the directions and pass the response to a
        // function to create markers for each step.
        this.directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            var warnings = document.getElementById('warnings_panel');
            warnings.innerHTML = '<b>' + response.routes[0].warnings + '</b>';
            this.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            gmaps.showSteps(response);
            }
        });
        },

    showSteps: function(directionResult) {
        // For each step, place a marker, and add the text to the marker's
        // info window. Also attach the marker to an array so we
        // can keep track of it and remove it when calculating new
        // routes.
        var myRoute = directionResult.routes[0].legs[0];

        for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myRoute.steps[i].start_location,
                map: map.instance
            });
            gmaps.attachInstructionText(marker, myRoute.steps[i].instructions);
            this.markerArray[i] = marker;
        }
        },

         attachInstructionText: function(marker, text) {

        // Instantiate an info window to hold step text.
        var stepDisplay = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
            // Open an info window when the marker is clicked on,
            // containing the text of the step.
            stepDisplay.setContent(text);
            stepDisplay.open(map.instance, marker);

        })

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                map.instance.setZoom(14);
                map.instance.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                stepDisplay.open(map.instance, marker);
            })

        },

        clearMarkers: function() {

              // First, remove any existing markers from the map.
        for (var i = 0; i < this.markerArray.length; i++) {

            this.markerArray[i].setMap(null);
        }

        // Now, clear the array itself.
        this.markerArray = [];

        }



});

Template.map.onCreated(function() {
    GoogleMaps.ready('map', function(map) {



        var bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
        bikeLayer.setMap(map.instance);



        var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(29.71739, -95.40183),
            map: map.instance,
            title: 'Rice U Farmers Market'            
        });        
        var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: ''
          });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
            infowindow1.setContent( '<p>Farmers Market at Rice U </p>' +'<button onclick="Meteor.call(calcRoute());">Directions from my Location</button>');
            infowindow1.open(map.instance, marker1);
        });

        var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(29.81063, -95.37999),
            map: map.instance,
            title: 'Canino\'s Produce'            
        });
        var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: 'Canino\'s Produce'
          });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
            infowindow2.open(map.instance, marker2);
        });

        var image = '/img/app/flag1.png'
        var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.lat, pos.lng),
            map: map.instance,
            title: 'You are here',
            icon: image
        });

        var rendererOptions = {
            map: map.instance
        }

        this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        directionsDisplay = new                                                         google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

        // global flag saying we intialized already
        Session.set('map', true);
    })


});
```

Comment: Where is your *calcRoute* function defined? It seems from the code inside it that it's probably on the client in which case Meteor.call() is not required. You just need to have it in the same file as the caller and just invoke it directly as `calcRoute()` or you can create a global function.

Comment: it is defined in Template.map.helpers({}) and it is invoked in Template.map.onCreated({}). I thought I had defined it in the right place, but it is likely that I didn't. Where else could I define it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the name of the method that Meteor will call as a string;

Replace:

```
'<p>Farmers Market at Rice U </p>' +'<button onclick="Meteor.call(calcRoute());">Directions from my Location</button>');
        infowindow1.open(map.instance, marker1);
```

with:

```
'<p>Farmers Market at Rice U </p>' +'<button onclick="Meteor.call(\'calcRoute\');">Directions from my Location</button>');
        infowindow1.open(map.instance, marker1);
```

Comment: I received this error: Error invoking Method 'calcRoute': Method not found [404].... So I'm guess I defined it in the wrong place. It is in the Template.map.helper({}) function as of now

Comment: Ah you are right. Move the definition of calcRoute to Template.map.methods instead and it should work.

Comment: "Template.map.methods is not a function" is what I am getting in the console :/

Comment: I'm sorry. my bad. Actually methods get added directly to Meteor. Use Meteor.methods({calcRoute: function(){}})